# Play Writes with generic type parameters

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a trait `Processor` that looks like this:

```
trait Processor[A] {
  def process(in: Seq[Byte]): Result[A]
}

trait Result[A]{
  val ok: Boolean
  val errorMessage: Option[String]
  val data: Option[A]
}
```

A concrete implementation:

```
class StringProc extends Processor[String] {
  def process(in: Seq[Byte]): StrResult
}

case class StrResult(...) extends Result[String]
object StrResult {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[StrResult]
}
```

When using a `StringProc` instance as type `Processor[String]`, the return type of `process` unsurprisingly is `Result[String]`, not `StrResult`. Unfortunately, the `Writes[StrResult]` seems to be useless in this case:

> No Json serializer found for type Result[String]

How could I handle this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
object Result {
  implicit def resWrites[T](implicit nested: Writes[T]): Writes[Result[T]] = OWrites[Result[T]] { res =>
    Json.obj("ok" -> res.ok, "errorMessage" -> res.errorMessage,
      "data" -> nested.writes(res.data))
  }
}
```

Comment: The line within the object gives me _No unapply or unapplySeq function found_ . Maybe because `Result[A]` is a trait and not a class?

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to find out how it works, but it does work ;) The trick is that the nested writes is automatically provided by the compiler, right?

Comment: There is no trick, that's just the standard way the implicit scope is working.